# Can someone explain the following MIPs code?

Tags: arrays, mips, sll

f,g,h,i,j == $s0-$s4. 
Base address of arrays A and B are $s6 and $s7

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2
add $t0, $s6, $t0
sll $t1, $s1, 2
add $t1, $s7, $t1
lw $s0, 0($t0)
```

as far as i understand, the first line takes the value of f*4 and stores it in $t0. ive been told that we have the first line because the array is holding 4-byte values. Please explain the rest. I know the program is accessing the array somewhere but i dont understand the syntax, it just looks like the base case of array A is being added to the f*4. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sll` is shift-left-logical -- so `sll $t0, $s0, 2` takes the value in `$s0` (f), and shifts it left by 2 bit places, sticking the result is `$t0`.  That's the same as multiplying by 4, but much faster.

`add` is addition -- so `add $t0, $s6, $t0` takes the value in `$s6` (the base address of A), and adds the `$t0` value just computed above, sticking the result in `$t0` (replacing the old value).  This gives you the address of A[f]

`lw` is load word -- so `lw $s0, 0($t0)` loads the 4-byte value at a 0 byte offset from `$t0` and sticks it in `$s0`.  Given the previous two instructions, this is the value of A[f]

The other two instructions are computing the address of B[g] in `$t1`